# how can I use WebSockets in Bluemix Liberty fro Java

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud

when I created my `WAR` on `TomCat7` I could just implement `javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig` and the tomcat captured it and supported `WebSockets`.
When I did the same under my `BlueMix Liberty` project it does not seems to work on my `Eclipse` (it works on the BlueMix cloud, only on my Eclipse is does not).

Any clue what to configure in Eclipse to make it work?

Application Log:

```
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting     property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Hagglelot' did not find a     matching property.
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.65
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 9 2015 08:36:58 UTC
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.65.0
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener     log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:             D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.65
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.65
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.65\endorsed
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program     Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CloudFoundry;C:\Users\ran\Desktop;;.
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2448 ms
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.65
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:57 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [111] milliseconds.
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 15, 2015 1:51:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2216 ms
Dec 15, 2015 1:56:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/JavaHelloWorldApp] has started
Dec 15, 2015 1:56:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Dec 15, 2015 1:56:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/JavaHelloWorldApp] is completed
```

Comment: Update: on the actual bluemix cloud it works fine. That makes it more an eclipse question...

Comment: What error do you get running it in Eclipse?

Comment: basically I get a 404, but the main reason is that I do not see Tomcat locating my ServerEndpointConfig implmention... it should do that automatically

Comment: In this case you should see an Exception in the application server logs. Could you share that with us?

Comment: added in the original question, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ran, however in the logs I see only that the application correctly started (if its name is JavaHelloWorldApp). Could you please do an action to get the 404 and attach the logs after doing that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97975/discussion-between-ran-cohen-and-umberto-manganiello).